# How to manage the git such that I can have custom commit on top of other project

Tags: git

My project is based on an open source project.
I have some custom commit based on it.

So, basically, my project and the open source project would both have new commits as time passed.

How the git should be setup so that I can always have my commits based on the latest open source code easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you planning to contribute your commits back to the main project<sup>*</sup>?

1. If not, then you can just create a topic branch off of master then periodically pull from upstream and rebase your branch.

   ```
   git clone clone-url
   git checkout -b your-topic-branch
   # work on your branch
   git checkout master
   git pull origin master
   git rebase master your-topic-branch
   ```
2. If yes, the main project should have instructions about their workflow.

<sup>*</sup>Depending on the license you might be required to do this if you are going to redistribute your work.

Edit please note the `-b` option passed in to the second command.